# References for linear relations on Hilbert spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am trying to find a reference for linear relations (multivalued operators). I would like to have something which gives an introductory overview.

All I have found so far doesn't seem right for people that are new to this concept.
The closest I could find was the book *Multivalued linear operators* by *Ronald Cross*. However, I don't limit myself to books I am also more than happy with a compact article/paper.

Comment: Appendix A of the book "The Functional Calculus for Sectorial Operators (2006)" by Markus Haase contains some material on multi-valued operators.

Comment: @JochenGlueck thanks, I think this will do the job.